# Cannot load file mysql2 on AWS Lambda

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Trying to have a Lambda connect to an RDS database but can't get the mysql2 gem to load. Tried the **pristine** instruction but that didn't resolve the issue.

I've got the built mysql2 gem in the vendor directory. Did this using **bundle install --deployment**.

Presumably this is a problem because of the compiled extensions used by mysql2. Not sure how I can sort this for AWS Lambda though. Thoughts?

Here's the log output:

```
START RequestId: 62f35c49-039f-11e9-be04-1fd1111df42b Version: $LATEST
Ignoring mysql2-0.5.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.5.2
Init error when loading handler lambda_function.lambda_handler
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- mysql2",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'"
  ]
}
END RequestId: 62f35c49-039f-11e9-be04-1fd1111df42b
REPORT RequestId: 62f35c49-039f-11e9-be04-1fd1111df42b  Duration: 1439.17 ms    Billed Duration: 1500 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 17 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
Init<LoadError>
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.2'
gem 'sequel', '~> 5.15.0'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
  mysql2 (0.5.2)
  sequel (5.15.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  mysql2 (~> 0.5.2)
  sequel (~> 5.15.0)

BUNDLED WITH
  1.17.2
```

Here's the top of my lambda_function.rb file

```
require 'json'
require 'logger'
require 'mysql2'
require 'sequel'
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to read it entirely yet but seems like I can use Docker to build the gem and its extensions in an environment similar to that which Lambda uses. See [here](https://blog.honeybadger.io/using-ruby-on-aws-lamba/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prerequesties:
* Docker

Create a docker file like this

```
    FROM lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.5
    RUN yum -y install mysql-devel
    RUN gem update bundler
    CMD "/bin/bash"
```

Build the docker

```
    docker build -t lambda-ruby2.5-mysqldep .
```

Docker run in your source code folder with the below command

```
    docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/var/task -w /var/task lambda-ruby2.5-mysqldep
```

It will get you into the bash
Inside the bash

- move the mysql folder from /usr/lib64/mysql to /usr/mysql
- mkdir -p /var/task/lib
- cp -a /usr/mysql/*.so.* /var/task/lib/
- bundle config --local build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
- bundle install with and without deployment

Then exit the bash. And create a lambda deployment package and upload it to AWS. It worked for me

Comment: like RUN yum -y install mysql-devel is there any command for postgres10

Answer (score 2):

Dhanabal's answer works but lets me elaborate more since the answer is too procedural for me.

Basically, a gem with native extension should build on the same environment as AWS Lambda.
So we need to build native extension inside `lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.5` docker image that mimics Lambda environment.

Also, we need to copy dynamic libraries into the load path.
First, let's find out where can we place the libraries.
`echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the container and you'll get
`/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib`.
So, I simply copy the library from `/usr/lib64/mysql` to `[function dir]/lib` and deploy.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. Excellent point on giving the why as well as the how.

Comment: When I bash into the docker container `var/task/lib` I see the `*.so` files. But when I exit the docker container I see `lib` directory is empty. Do I need to map them ? I get `libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when I execute the lambda function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62218696/libmysqlclient-so-18-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Docker is kinda complicated. I cannot speak for your setup but for me, I used docker-compose for development. I mount my entire code dir into the container in the development environment. I have Makefile for packing the zip file, I perform the copy operation there. Here some observe from my Makefile `docker-compose run --rm application cp $(shell docker-compose run --rm application realpath /usr/lib64/libnettle.so.4) ./lib/libnettle.so.4` it is not the MySQL library though, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

2 things about Dhanabal's answer

1) cp -a /usr/mysql/.so step is missing a *
2) Make sure there are no sym links in the lib directory, you need actual files because symlinks break after they are zipped up.