# libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, mysql2

I'm currently trying to AWS Lambda a Ruby application. I was having issues installing `mysql2`, when I ran `bundle install` I was getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling
```

I came across a Stackoverflow post to create a Docker container to load the dependencies, here is the post. [Cannot load file mysql2 on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854487/cannot-load-file-mysql2-on-aws-lambda)

I followed the steps in the post:

```
move the mysql folder from /usr/lib64/mysql to /usr/mysql
mkdir -p /var/task/lib
cp -a /usr/mysql/.so. /var/task/lib/
bundle config --local build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
bundle install with and without deployment
```

and I was able to install, as mentioned in the post the files can not be symlink because it breaks once you `zip` the directory. I tried using `mv` but the files don't persist in the directory after I exit the container. Once I `zip` the application and deploy to AWS Lambda I get the following error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/task/my_sql.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'"
  ]
}
```

But I'm able to see the file `mysql2.so` in the vendor directory:

```
bash-4.2# cd /var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/
bash-4.2# ls
client.rb  console.rb  em.rb  error.rb  field.rb  mysql2.so  result.rb  statement.rb  version.rb
bash-4.2#
```

I'm also able to see the files `libmysqlclient.so` and `/mysql2/mysql2.so`.
[image]
[image]

Why it is not finding the file?

Comment: if you want to map the lib dir to docker container var/task/lib then use docker volumes, But I am not able to understand your problem. What is your problem? You are able to copy the lib and are you able to run the application in docker container or not ?